# issue related to undefined control sequence

Tags: underline, sectsty

My first post on here. If I fail to abide by the rule, apologies beforehand :)

My code run months ago without error.
When I try it this time, after updating my MikTex, it sows me the following error message:

All my references are preceded with the error messages similar to the one below.
I would appreciate if anyone would give me a hint.
I have already tried to delete the aux file and rerun my code. It did not solve it.

The following are my packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}            
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            
\usepackage[english]{babel}     
\usepackage{graphicx}               
\usepackage{subfigure}              
\usepackage{lscape}              
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={red},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={red}} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\centering}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
```

````
! Undefined control sequence.
l.34 \abx@aux@segm
                  {0}{0}{uribe2006country}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.35 \abx@aux@cite
                  {fogli2006great}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.```
````

Comment: Try deleting your `.aux` file(s) and re-running LaTeX.

Comment: you are showing commands expected in an aux file of a document using biblatex, but the fragment you show is using natbib. as DonH says, you should remove the aux file

Comment: Yeah. `\abx@aux@segm` is a `biblatex` command that is written to the `.aux` file. Your document no longer loads `biblatex` so the command is undefined now. Just delete the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`) and compile again (the error comes from the `.aux` file, so it might be enough to delete that, but it is probably better to get rid of all temp files.)

Comment: Great! It indeed work after removing  .aux file. Thank you all, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was caused by the presence of biblatex commands in a document specifying `natbib`; the OP reported that this was fixed by removing the `.aux` files.

Comment: Yes please. The above suggestions helped me solve the issue.